# Run node.js after switching user in a script

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
su newuser
node index.js
```

This script is an entrypoint for a docker container.

When I run the container, I see that the script gets executed and I switch to newuser. However, index.js does not get called. But as soon as I type "exit" to exit newuser, index.js starts running.

Can someone explain what the problem is here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su newuser` will create a new shell.  Basically, that command launches a process that takes time to exit.  Only once it exits will the next command in your original bash script execute.

If you want to run node as newuser, use this command instead:

```
su newuser -c "node index.js"
```

Probably you want to include the full path to node as well, because launching scripts this way often doesn't bring up the full environment that you might expect (PATH might not be complete compared to running a full shell):

```
su newuser -c "/path/to/node index.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the script is an entrypoint script, you shouldn’t need to set the username at all; a USER directive in the Dockerfile can set the (default) user name or user ID.

For this simple setup I wouldn’t use an entrypoint script at all.  I’d put in my Dockerfile

```
USER newuser
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

In general I’d avoid entrypoint scripts or ENTRYPOINT directives that run fixed commands (and prefer CMD over ENTRYPOINT) because they make it difficult to do the otherwise very-useful-when-things-are-broken

```
docker run --rm -it myimage sh
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, but in my case this is not an option as I need to change the user AFTER performing some operations in the script. I omitted those steps for clarity. But I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: I've seen https://github.com/tianon/gosu used for that case.  As the accepted answer suggests, this is mostly about getting the syntax and quoting right.